# Parsing YAML containing multiple documents and accessing objects

Tags: perl, yaml

I am trying to get data from a YAML file for my Perl script.

Following is a similar sample scenario:

Let us consider a YAML file for employee data.

```
---
emp_name: John
emp_age: 27
DOB: 1/1/1990
others:
  - key1: value1
  - key2: value2
---
emp_name: Doe
emp_age: 25
DOB: 1/1/1992
others:
  - key1: value1
  - key2: value2
---
emp_name: foo
emp_age: 22
DOB: 1/1/1995
others:
  - key1: value1
  - key2: value2
---
emp_name: Bar
emp_age: 21
DOB: 1/1/1996
others:
  - key1: value1
  - key2: value2
...
```

I have the above four set of values. I'm trying to get all employee names saved in an array, but I'm unable to get it.

With `Dumper` I am able to print only the first section (John's) file as a JSON. I'm not able to get individual values (eg. get all employee name in an array).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::XS 'LoadFile';
use Data::Dumper;
my $config = LoadFile('input2.yml');
print Dumper($config), '\n';
print "Expected output:\n";
print "John \nDoe \nfoo \nBar\n";
print "--- Actual Output --";
my $empName;
for(my $i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
$empName = $config->[$i]->{emp_name};
}
```

Any help?

The above is the code. I would like to fetch list of employee names, but I get an error:

> Not an ARRAY reference at yamlParser.pl line 15

Comment: What is the _dumper_ you are referring to? Please show the JSON output that matches your YAML input.

Comment: Ok, and how do you read the `$configFile`? Please show your code, what it outputs and what you want it to output instead.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding: The output of [`Data::Dumper`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is _**not**_ JSON. It's Perl's data representation of a given variable. – Although it often contains many `{}` and `[]` characters.

Comment: Attached code above! There should be some newbie silly mistakes I guess :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yaml presented offers 4 documents, not an array of 4 items, so you just need to dereference those.  Have a read of the docs:
[perldoc YAML::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~tinita/YAML-LibYAML-0.66/lib/YAML/XS.pod)

Change:

```
my $config = LoadFile('input2.yml');
```

To:

```
my @conf = LoadFile('input2.yml');
my $config = \@conf;
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation?

Comment: Probably LoadFile returns different things when called in list vs. scalar context. I thougt the YAML isn't valid and has to be indented and preceeded with a dash for each record. But the `@conf` thingy is far cooler.

Comment: `YAML::LoadFile` returns a list of data structures represented by each independent YAML document inside the stream. In scalar context, as with any list being assigned, this will be the last element in that list. I think the OP has overlooked that when saying it was the first section (John's).

Comment: The YAML file in the question is syntactically correct and valid. But I sincerely doubt the correctness off it, considering `- key1: value1` and `- key2: value2` is probably not what the OP wants. That is generating a list containing 2 elements, each a hashref like { key1 => 'value1' }, { key2 => 'value2' }`; Others` is **not** a single hash with two key/value pairs in it like `{ key1 => 'value1, key2 => `value2` }` -- of course, it could be what the OP wanted, but such construct usually is only required when the same key can be used within the same level, with different values, like CGI query

Comment: Thanks all. Is there a way to pick a particular value from any of the document on demand without traversing all the documents? For example if I need to pick the age of Doe, is there a straight forward way?

Comment: I've added two solutions on my answer - based on the corrected YAML - for printing the employee age. There is a reason why in real-life, we use Social-Security numbers or other ways to uniquely identify people - and use ID's in databases etc. --- You can probably figure out how to hold my solution around the answers given by others. - The true nightmare starts when trying to do something with the info stored under `other:` and will see why I recommended to correct the YAML file - that is, that would be the right thing to do, if you are the creator of that file too

Answer (score 2):

Unlike JSON, YAML may contain multiple documents. Each of them begins with `---` in the data stream, and the end of the last document is indicated by `...`

The YAML data that you are using contains four such documents, which are returned by `LoadFile` as a list of references. If you assign that list to a scalar variable then it will pick up the last element, so you need to put the result into an array (or a list of scalar variables)

This code will do as you ask. It retrieves the YAML data into array `@config` and then uses `map` to extract the `emp_name` element of each hash

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use YAML::XS 'LoadFile';

my @config = LoadFile 'input2.yml';

my @names = map { $_->{emp_name} } @config;

say for @names;
```

#### output

```
John
Doe
foo
Bar
```

Comment: Thanks all. Is there a way to pick a particular value from any of the document on demand without traversing all the documents? For example if I need to pick the age of Doe, is there a straight forward way?

Answer (score -1):

Let us first consider some basic knowledge about YAML, instead of the file itself.

A file containing a **YAML stream** can contain multiple *unrelated* **YAML documents** of complete different data structure, separated by `---`.

Your file seems to contain *records* of the same structure and you probably wanted only one document, containing a **YAML sequence** of *records*, each record being a **YAML mapping**.

Below is what you SHOULD have had:

```
- emp_name: John
  emp_age: 27
  DOB: 1/1/1990
  others:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
- emp_name: Doe
  emp_age: 25
  DOB: 1/1/1992
  others:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
- emp_name: foo
  emp_age: 22
  DOB: 1/1/1995
  others:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
- emp_name: Bar
  emp_age: 21
  DOB: 1/1/1996
  others:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

*note the difference; 1 document; each record starts with the line containing the `-`; `others` is now a true **mapping** and not a **sequence** of single mappings (`- key: value`, removed the `-`)*

Now the following code would read the contents of the file, into a single variable, that holds an ArrayRef to the entire data structure of that **single YAML document**.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;

my $data = YAML::LoadFile('input2_correct.yml');

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $data;
```

FYI: using `YAML::LoadFile` in list context reads all the seperate documents.

Please fix your YAML file!

From this point on, one can easily use `map` to manipulate the Perl data structure in a hash, if needed, or print the names:

```
print "$_->{emp_name}\n" foreach @$data;
```

Or, if you want to print the age off all 'Doe' records ...

```
my $name = 'Doe';

foreach my $emp_record ( @$data ) {
    next unless $emp_record->{emp_name} eq $name;
    # do what you like to do with the record
    print "$emp_record->{emp_age}\n";
}
```

If there is only ever going to be 1 record 'Doe', the code below will print the age for the *first* 'Doe':

```
my ($found) = grep { $_->{emp_name} eq $name } @$data;
print "$found->{emp_age}\n";
```

*`grep` will reduce the list to only those that evaluate true in the given expression. `my (found)` causes a list context for grep and will be assigned the first of the reduced list*